# Select nested element text property

Tags: jquery

I have this html

```
<div id="content">
  <div id="rightnow">
    <h3 class="reallynow">
      <span style="float:left;">Client Dashboard</span>
    </h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I access the `<span>` element's text property using JQuery?

PS: I may have other `reallynow` elements in my DOM

Comment: sorry this is offtopic, but after just recently getting 3k rep with ability to vote to close, it sure seems like mods on this site are trigger happy to close questions.

Comment: I completely agree, thats what I voted to keep it open. Every one of the 5 mods listed below should be ashamed of themselves.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var theText = $('#rightnow > h3.reallynow > span').text();
```

As you said you may have other `.reallynow` elements, I've tried to make it as specific as possible, using the ID, the span's parent (h3) and the direct child selector. This is as foolproof as possible without knowing all your markup.

Comment: You could add 'h3.reallynow' to be even more specific ;)

Answer (score 3):

Combined Class and id selectors, though there are so many ways to do it!

```
$("#rightnow .reallynow span").text()
```

For the direct parent child relationship

Try

```
$("#rightnow > h3.reallynow > span").text()
```

Child selector [*API*](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/)

Answer (score 1):

To read...

```
var text = $('#rightnow .reallynow span').text();
```

to write...

```
$('#rightnow .reallynow span').text("your text");
```